# copy and rename script

Tags: shell, scripting

```
Directory A:
        1111111_1.pdf
        2222222_1.pdf
        1234567_1.pdf
Directory B:
        abcdefg.pdf
        zzzzzzz.pdf
        1234567.pdf
        1111111.pdf
        2222222.pdf
        aaaaaaa.pdf
        bbbbbbb.pdf
        etc....
        …....
```

What method should I use to write a shell script to copy only 3 same 7digit like files from directory B to A and then rename to be `_2.pdf` result like  this:

```
Directory A:
        1111111_1.pdf
        1111111_2.pdf
        2222222_1.pdf
        2222222_2.pdf
        1234567_1.pdf
        1234567_2.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will do what you want:

```
cd A
B=../B  # Put path to B here
for a in *_1.pdf; do b=${a%_1.pdf}; [ -f "$B/$b.pdf" ] && cp "$B/$b.pdf" "${b}_2.pdf" ; done
```

If the code above is to be put in a script, as opposed to typed at a command line, it would look better with line breaks and indentation:

```
cd A
B=../B  # Put path to B here
for a in *_1.pdf
do 
    b=${a%_1.pdf}
    [ -f "$B/$b.pdf" ] && cp "$B/$b.pdf" "${b}_2.pdf"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you ask for:

```
for i in A/*_1.pdf
do
  root=${i#A/}
  root=${root%_1.pdf}

  if [ -f "B/${root}.pdf" ]
  then
    cp -i "B/${root}.pdf" "A/${root}_2.pdf"
  fi
done
```

It simply finds every file in A for which there is a matching file in B, and copies accordingly.  It uses shell parameter expansion to manipulate the filenames from one form to the other.

It doesn't restrict to just 7-digit names; it wasn't clear whether you wanted that or if it was just to aid explaining in the question.  It will also be more complex if you want it to work for numbers other than 1 and 2.

I used `cp -i` to avoid accidental overwrites.  Remove the `-i` if you want it to overwrite existing files.